Compute p-value of Earth Mover's distance score comparing two heatmaps in R?
I am trying to compare two heatmaps and can't find a way to obtain a statistically meaningful value.
Here, my issue: I measured the single response to a panel of 5 drugs. Individual cells belong to two conditions A and B. Based on the overall collection of single cell responses, I generated a clustering of these responses and identify "10" profiles of responses (referred here as "Cluster").
To evaluate differences between conditions A and B, I generate a heatmap for each conditions representing the proportion of cells subjected to each drugs to be associated to each cluster.
This represent somehow a footprint of the cellular response of each conditions to the panel of drugs. I see obvious difference into the patterns and was wondering if there is a way to define if distributed in two groups submitted to various treatments.
Looking on the web, I found about the Earth Mover's distance (EMD) and compare both matrix using emddist R package. I obtain a value (if I understand correctly) which is somehow an index of dissimilarity between my two heatmaps.
Now, I'm wondering if there is anyway to associate a significant p-value of this value ?
How can I conclude that both heatmaps/distributions are "significantly" different (or not) ?
Am I on the right path regarding my initial question to compare the distribution of cellular response to different drugs ?
Examples are better than words, so please find here a minimal reproducible example of my current issue:
set.seed(123)
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(50, 2), 10, 5)
mat1 <- apply(mat1,2, function(x) x/sum(x))
mat1

mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(50, 2), 10, 5)
mat2 <- apply(mat2,2, function(x) x/sum(x))
mat2

Here the code generating the "footprint" of  each condition:
library(ComplexHeatmap)
HT1 <- Heatmap(mat1, cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE, name = "matrix1",column_title = "Condition A",
               column_labels = paste0("Drug ",1:5), row_labels = paste0("Cluster ",1:10))
HT2 <- Heatmap(mat2, cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE, name = "matrix2",column_title = "Condition B",
               column_labels = paste0("Drug ",1:5), row_labels = paste0("Cluster ",1:10))
HT1 + HT2

And finally my current try of EMD computation:
library(emddist)
> emd2d(mat1,mat2)
[1] 0.42168


NB: I'm working on R, so a solution or a suggestion implying a R package will be greatly appreciated

In general, what you have here is a 3-way contingency matrix. That is the most general formulation. You may want to check here, or here (this last one as a good survey of all possible ways to analyze such 3-way tables).
It kind of depends on what you are trying to test for, but from the question it seems you are trying to test whether the distribution of cell responses accross the various drugs/clusters is (or not) dependent on the condition (compare 2 2x2 tables). The answer to this is most likely the Cochran-Mantel-Haenzel test. It will test the independence of the distributions, conditional on the condition, and will give you a p-value.
The 2nd link, and this link have some example of R-code.
Note that you could also run a 3x3 $\chi^2$ test, which would test for mutual independence (which does not seem to ne what you want), but I am afraid that you would have to do so by hand (compute all expected counts by hand, compute the squared differences by hand, etc., compute the d.f. by hand -these are all simple extensions of the 2x2 case) and then use a $\chi^2$ table.
